# xamarin FFImageLoading exception "Forbidden"

Tags: xamarin.forms, ffimageloading

I was trying out FFImageLoading for Xamarin Forms by following [this example](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki/Xamarin.Forms-API) (xaml-version)

but I get an exception in my error handler, originating inthe plugins' DownloadCache.cs with the message "Forbidden" and the stack trade below

> at FFImageLoading.Retry+d__01[T].MoveNext () [0x0015b] in
>   C:\projects\ffimageloading\source\FFImageLoading.Common\Helpers\Retry.cs:32
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
>   [0x0000c] in :0 at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in
>   :0 at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in
>   :0 at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in
>   :0 at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult
>   () [0x00000] in :0 at
>   FFImageLoading.Cache.DownloadCache+d__16.MoveNext () [0x00413] in
>   C:\projects\ffimageloading\source\FFImageLoading.Common\Cache\DownloadCache.cs:58
>
> ..../goes on for a while/

Im running android and tested both enableFastRenderer true (in linked guide) and false I have been writing to file system loaded loaded images from urls in same project.

Comment: What is the Image URL that you are trying to load?

Comment: From the example (http://loremflickr.com/600/600/nature?filename=simple.jpg). I also tried "first" google image image and copied the link